# in Asp.net MVC Project calling an action through ajax not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Im doing an Asp.net-MVC Project and I want to call action `IHelp` through ajax but its not working at all, in debugger, code doesn't come into success loop, It seems some problem with controller

here is my controller:

```
 public JsonResult IHelp(int dataid)
    {
        var ajaxq = db.Questions.Where(e => e.CategoryId == dataid).Select(e => new
        {
            quest = e.Qu,
            answe = e.Ans
        }).ToList();

        return Json(ajaxq);

    }
```

this is my html

```
<nav class="row" id="iconsinhelp">
    <ul class="">
        <li data-id=1 class="col-md-2">

            <div class="">
                <div class="margin0auto  width80px">
                    <img src="~/Content/img/help/before-you-travel-0.png" />
                    <img src="~/Content/img/help/before-you-travel-1.png" />
                </div>

            </div>
            <p class="">Before You Travel</p>

        </li>
        <li data-id=2 class="col-md-2">

            <div>
                <div class="margin0auto  width80px">
                    <img src="~/Content/img/help/your-flights-0.png" />
                    <img src="~/Content/img/help/your-flights-1.png" />
                </div>

            </div>
            <p>You'r Flights</p>


        </li>
        <li data-id=3 class="col-md-2">

            <div>

                <div class="margin0auto  width80px">
                    <img src="~/Content/img/help/on holiday-0.png" />
                    <img src="~/Content/img/help/on holiday-1.png" />
                </div>


            </div>
            <p>On Holiday</p>

        </li>
        <li data-id=4 class="col-md-2">

            <div>

                <div class="margin0auto  width80px">
                    <img src="~/Content/img/help/when-you-hetback-0.png" />
                    <img src="~/Content/img/help/when-you-hetback-1.png" />

                </div>


            </div>
            <p>When You Get Back</p>

        </li>
        <li data-id=5 class="col-md-2">

            <div>

                <div class="margin0auto  width80px">

                    <img src="~/Content/img/help/travel-advice-&-safety-0.png" />
                    <img src="~/Content/img/help/travel-advice-&-safety-1.png" />

                </div>


            </div>
            <p>Travel Advice & Safety</p>

        </li>
        <li data-id=6 class="col-md-2 ficon">

            <div>
                <div class="margin0auto  width80px">
                    <img src="~/Content/img/help/payment-0.png" />

                    <img src="~/Content/img/help/payment-1.png" />
                </div>





            </div>
            <p>Payments</p>

        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

and this is my ajax code

```
   $("#iconsinhelp li").click(function () {
    var self = this;
    alert($(self).data('id'));
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Home/IHelp/' + $(self).data('id'),
        type: 'POST',


        success: function (result) {

            alert();
        }
    });
});
```

and this is what I put in route config

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

Comment: What routes have you defined in your routeconfig?

Comment: @danm thank you so much I added the route config at the end

Comment: @nedaDerakhshesh are you getting any error in console of browser? and did you place a break point to check weather it is going to action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since your default route has `{id}` it will consider the `/1` as parameter `id` but in your action the name of parameter is `int dataid` thats why it will get `0` in the `dataid` so you can do

```
 public JsonResult IHelp(int id)
    {
        var ajaxq = db.Questions.Where(e => e.CategoryId == id).Select(e => new
        {
            quest = e.Qu,
            answe = e.Ans
        }).ToList();

        return Json(ajaxq);

    }
```

change name from `dataid` to `id` or you can set `dataid`  like this

```
url: '/Home/IHelp?dataid=' + $(self).data('id'),
```

Comment: thank you after I changed `dataid` to id it works fine, really thank you.